# [Warning]-App Check Flutter Fire On Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

Got This Error

I Search On Google error means that's attestation failed, so how to fix it because i need the token for access my firebase storage here my code

```
const androidProvider =
    kReleaseMode ? AndroidProvider.playIntegrity : AndroidProvider.debug;
const appleProvider = kReleaseMode
    ? AppleProvider.appAttestWithDeviceCheckFallback
    : AppleProvider.debug;
final webProvider =
    isWeb ? ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(kWebRecaptchaSiteKey) : null;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await dotenv.load(fileName: 'lib/.env');
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webProvider: webProvider,
    androidProvider: androidProvider,
  );
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```